# Angular toJson is not serializing all properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a javascript object that looks like:

```
var Person = function() {

    var _name = "";

    this.Age = 0;

    Object.defineProperty(this, "Name", {
        get: function () { return _name; },
        set: function (value) { _name = value; }
    });
}
```

When I use the function angular.toJson it skips the Name property in the resulting json string:

{"Age":17}

How do I (can I) get angular.toJson to include the Name property in the JSON string? If I can't do that what are my alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only enumerable properties can be serialized into JSON. By default, [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) does not make properties enumerable. Here's how to make it enumerable.

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 'Name', {
  enumerable: true, // <--
  get: function() { return _name; },
  set: function(value) { _name = value; }
});
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!